# Make stops everytime on a different file

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to compile some libraries with make, such as Opencv and I'm just curious about it's behaviour. When I run make for example 3 times, it stops and gives error on different files each time while linking. There's also different percentage each time. What does it mean? Make builts targets always in different order or what?

[edit] add output of `make`, don't know if anything can be find out from it.

```
[ 69%] Building CXX object modules/cudastereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudastereo.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_cudastereo
[ 69%] Built target opencv_test_cudastereo
[ 71%] Built target opencv_datasets
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_ar_hmdb.dir/samples/ar_hmdb.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_ar_hmdb
[ 71%] Built target example_datasets_ar_hmdb
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_ar_hmdb_benchmark.dir/samples/ar_hmdb_benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_ar_hmdb_benchmark
[ 71%] Built target example_datasets_ar_hmdb_benchmark
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_ar_sports.dir/samples/ar_sports.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_ar_sports
[ 71%] Built target example_datasets_ar_sports
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_fr_adience.dir/samples/fr_adience.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_fr_adience
[ 71%] Built target example_datasets_fr_adience
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_fr_lfw.dir/samples/fr_lfw.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_fr_lfw
[ 71%] Built target example_datasets_fr_lfw
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_fr_lfw_benchmark.dir/samples/fr_lfw_benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_fr_lfw_benchmark
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_fr_lfw_benchmark
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_gr_chalearn.dir/samples/gr_chalearn.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_gr_chalearn
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_gr_chalearn
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_gr_skig.dir/samples/gr_skig.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_gr_skig
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_gr_skig
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_hpe_humaneva.dir/samples/hpe_humaneva.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_hpe_humaneva
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_hpe_humaneva
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_hpe_parse.dir/samples/hpe_parse.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_hpe_parse
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_hpe_parse
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_ir_affine.dir/samples/ir_affine.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_ir_affine
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_ir_affine
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_ir_robot.dir/samples/ir_robot.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_ir_robot
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_ir_robot
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_is_bsds.dir/samples/is_bsds.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_is_bsds
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_is_bsds
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_is_weizmann.dir/samples/is_weizmann.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_is_weizmann
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_is_weizmann
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_msm_epfl.dir/samples/msm_epfl.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_msm_epfl
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_msm_epfl
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_msm_middlebury.dir/samples/msm_middlebury.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_msm_middlebury
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_msm_middlebury
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_or_imagenet.dir/samples/or_imagenet.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_or_imagenet
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_or_imagenet
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_or_mnist.dir/samples/or_mnist.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_or_mnist
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_or_mnist
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_or_pascal.dir/samples/or_pascal.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_or_pascal
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_or_pascal
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_or_sun.dir/samples/or_sun.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_or_sun
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_or_sun
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_pd_caltech.dir/samples/pd_caltech.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_pd_caltech
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_pd_caltech
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_pd_inria.dir/samples/pd_inria.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_pd_inria
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_pd_inria
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_slam_kitti.dir/samples/slam_kitti.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_slam_kitti
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_slam_kitti
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_slam_tumindoor.dir/samples/slam_tumindoor.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_slam_tumindoor
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_slam_tumindoor
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_chars.dir/samples/tr_chars.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_chars
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_chars
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_chars_benchmark.dir/samples/tr_chars_benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_chars_benchmark
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_chars_benchmark
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_icdar.dir/samples/tr_icdar.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_icdar
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_icdar
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_icdar_benchmark.dir/samples/tr_icdar_benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_icdar_benchmark
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_icdar_benchmark
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_svt.dir/samples/tr_svt.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_svt
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_svt
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_tr_svt_benchmark.dir/samples/tr_svt_benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_tr_svt_benchmark
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_tr_svt_benchmark
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/example_datasets_track_vot.dir/samples/track_vot.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_datasets_track_vot
[ 72%] Built target example_datasets_track_vot
[ 72%] Built target opencv_rgbd_pch_dephelp
[ 72%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_rgbd
[ 72%] Built target opencv_rgbd
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/example_rgbd_linemod.dir/samples/linemod.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_rgbd_linemod
[ 72%] Built target example_rgbd_linemod
Scanning dependencies of target example_rgbd_odometry_evaluation
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/example_rgbd_odometry_evaluation.dir/samples/odometry_evaluation.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_rgbd_odometry_evaluation
[ 72%] Built target example_rgbd_odometry_evaluation
[ 72%] Built target opencv_test_rgbd_pch_dephelp
[ 72%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_rgbd
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_rgbd
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_rgbd.dir/test/test_utils.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_rgbd.dir/test/test_normal.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_rgbd.dir/test/test_odometry.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_rgbd.dir/test/test_precomp.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_rgbd.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_rgbd
[ 73%] Built target opencv_test_rgbd
[ 73%] Built target opencv_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 73%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_stereo
[ 73%] Built target opencv_stereo
Scanning dependencies of target example_stereo_sample
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/example_stereo_sample.dir/samples/sample.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_stereo_sample
[ 73%] Built target example_stereo_sample
[ 73%] Built target opencv_perf_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 73%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stereo
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_perf_stereo
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stereo.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stereo.dir/perf/perf_descriptor.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stereo.dir/perf/perf_bm.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_stereo
[ 74%] Built target opencv_perf_stereo
[ 74%] Built target opencv_test_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 74%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_stereo
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_stereo
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_stereo.dir/test/test_block_matching.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_stereo.dir/test/test_descriptors.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_stereo.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_stereo
[ 74%] Built target opencv_test_stereo
[ 74%] Built target opencv_structured_light_pch_dephelp
[ 74%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_structured_light
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/opencv_structured_light.dir/src/graycodepattern.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_structured_light.so
[ 74%] Built target opencv_structured_light
Scanning dependencies of target example_structured_light_cap_pattern
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/example_structured_light_cap_pattern.dir/samples/cap_pattern.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_structured_light_cap_pattern
[ 74%] Built target example_structured_light_cap_pattern
Scanning dependencies of target example_structured_light_pointcloud
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/example_structured_light_pointcloud.dir/samples/pointcloud.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_structured_light_pointcloud
[ 74%] Built target example_structured_light_pointcloud
[ 74%] Built target opencv_test_structured_light_pch_dephelp
[ 74%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_structured_light
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_structured_light
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_structured_light.dir/test/test_getProjPixel.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_structured_light.dir/test/test_plane.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object modules/structured_light/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_structured_light.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_structured_light
[ 74%] Built target opencv_test_structured_light
[ 74%] Built target opencv_perf_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 74%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_superres
[ 74%] Built target opencv_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 74%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_superres
[ 75%] Generating opencl_kernels_superres.cpp, opencl_kernels_superres.hpp
[ 75%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_btv_l1_gpu.cu.o
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/superres/src/cuda/btv_l1_gpu.cu: In function ‘void btv_l1_cudev::upscale(cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb, cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb, int, cudaStream_t)’:
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/superres/src/cuda/btv_l1_gpu.cu:129:67: warning: typedef ‘src_t’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef typename TypeVec<float, cn>::vec_type src_t;
                                                                   ^
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/superres/src/cuda/btv_l1_gpu.cu: In function ‘void btv_l1_cudev::calcBtvRegularization(cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb, cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb, int)’:
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/superres/src/cuda/btv_l1_gpu.cu:224:67: warning: typedef ‘src_t’ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef typename TypeVec<float, cn>::vec_type src_t;
                                                                   ^
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_superres
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/frame_source.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/super_resolution.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/optical_flow.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/btv_l1_cuda.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/btv_l1.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/src/input_array_utility.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/opencl_kernels_superres.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_superres.so
[ 75%] Built target opencv_superres
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_perf_superres
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_superres.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_superres.dir/perf/perf_superres.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_superres
[ 75%] Built target opencv_perf_superres
[ 77%] Built target opencv_test_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_superres
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_superres
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_superres.dir/test/test_superres.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_superres.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_superres
[ 77%] Built target opencv_test_superres
[ 77%] Built target opencv_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 77%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_tracking
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_tracking.so
[ 78%] Built target opencv_tracking
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_benchmark
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_benchmark.dir/samples/benchmark.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_benchmark
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_benchmark
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_kcf
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_kcf.dir/samples/kcf.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_kcf
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_kcf
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset.dir/samples/multiTracker_dataset.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_multitracker
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_multitracker.dir/samples/multitracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_multitracker
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_multitracker
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_tracker
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_tracker.dir/samples/tracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tracker
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_tracker
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_tracker_dataset
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_tracker_dataset.dir/samples/tracker_dataset.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tracker_dataset
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_tracker_dataset
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker.dir/samples/tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.dir/samples/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker
Scanning dependencies of target example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker.dir/samples/tutorial_multitracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker
[ 78%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker
[ 78%] Built target opencv_perf_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 78%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_tracking
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_perf_tracking
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_tracking.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_tracking.dir/perf/perf_Tracker.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_tracking
[ 78%] Built target opencv_perf_tracking
[ 78%] Built target opencv_test_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 78%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_tracking
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_tracking
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_trackerOPE.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_trackerTRE.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_trackerSRE.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_ukf.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_aukf.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/tracking/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_tracking.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_tracking
[ 78%] Built target opencv_test_tracking
[ 78%] Built target opencv_videostab_pch_dephelp
[ 78%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videostab
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_videostab
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/frame_source.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/inpainting.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/global_motion.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/motion_stabilizing.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/deblurring.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/optical_flow.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/stabilizer.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/wobble_suppression.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videostab.so
[ 79%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 79%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 79%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d
Scanning dependencies of target example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification.dir/samples/bagofwords_classification.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification
[ 80%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification
Scanning dependencies of target example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation.dir/samples/shape_transformation.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation
[ 80%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation
Scanning dependencies of target example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher.dir/samples/surf_matcher.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher
[ 80%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher
Scanning dependencies of target example_xfeatures2d_video_homography
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/example_xfeatures2d_video_homography.dir/samples/video_homography.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_video_homography
[ 80%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_video_homography
[ 80%] Built target opencv_perf_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 80%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_surf.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_surf.cuda.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_surf.ocl.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_daisy.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d.dir/perf/perf_latch.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Built target opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Built target opencv_test_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 80%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_xfeatures2d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_detectors.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_surf.cuda.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_features2d.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_keypoints.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_rotation_and_scale_invariance.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_surf.ocl.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_xfeatures2d.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Built target opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 81%] Built target opencv_ximgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 81%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ximgproc
[ 81%] Building CXX object modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp.o
In file included from /home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/ximgproc/precomp.hpp:40:
/home/tomas/opencv_contrib/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void cv::ximgproc::EdgeAwareInterpolatorImpl::interpolate(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray)’:
/home/tomas/opencv_contrib/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’
     CV_Assert( !from_points.empty() && from_points.isVector() &&
                                                    ^
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:389:33: note: in definition of macro ‘CV_Assert’
 #define CV_Assert( expr ) if(!!(expr)) ; else cv::error( cv::Error::StsAssert, #expr, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
                                 ^
/home/tomas/opencv_contrib/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:172:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’
                !to_points  .empty() && to_points  .isVector() &&
                                                    ^
/home/tomas/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:389:33: note: in definition of macro ‘CV_Assert’
 #define CV_Assert( expr ) if(!!(expr)) ; else cv::error( cv::Error::StsAssert, #expr, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
                                 ^
make[2]: *** [modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Unlikely, but if it doesn't break dependency graph - make is probably allowed to execute jobs in any order. Or maybe it just looks that way but actually is a result of multiple targets getting built in parallel (`make -jN`). Why does it even matter?

Comment: Percentages are going to be coming from cmake or similar and are just "estimates"/"guesses". The build may very well be being run in parallel (as keltar indicated) as well. If you'd like help with your actual linking problem you should post the details on that. I'm not sure this question, as asked, really has an answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am just trying to better understand make, cmakes and all this stuff. Because it always gives me different errors and I usually have no idea what could go wrong. @EtanReisner I think I messed up some include directories and paths in my system, everything I try to link fails. I don't even know what to ask exactly, I'll probably reinstall ubuntu and start from the begenning.

Comment: If you run make again without cleaning (e.g. `make clean`) then, given makefile is nice, it should just continue building. This is actually the main purpose of make - rebuild only required parts and not everything. So I guess cmake-injected percentages should be different, because 100% is no longer entire project but only remaining part.

Comment: @keltar I don't think cmake is that smart about percentages... though maybe it is.

Comment: Include directories don't affect linking. Library directories do. If you want to ask about the link errors then include the output from `make` when it fails.

Comment: @EtanReisner I included output of `make`, but I'm not sure if something can be read from it.

Comment: See if you can make it more verbose (or look higher up in the output than that). There's no actual error text in there. Also try without `-j5` to avoid the confusing output.

Comment: @EtanReisner Is this enough?

Comment: Yes. That's a compilation (not linker) error and that's a problem with the code. It is wrong/broken. `/home/tomas/opencv_contrib/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’`

Comment: So I can try to use something like `-DBUILD_opencv_ximgproc=OFF` in cmake and if there isn't error in other files it could pass. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct questions, not related to why your builds are failing:

- If you run make with the `-j` option it enables parallelism, which means many jobs run at the same time.  Depending on how long jobs take, which jobs succeeded last time vs. which are left to run, etc. it could be that they are started in a different order each time.  If you want a reproducible build that fails at the same place every time, don't use the `-j` flag.
- If you run make with the `-k` flag, it will keep going even after a failure, until it runs out of things that could be built without relying on any failed targets.  If you want make to stop immediately when it hits the first error, don't provide either the `-k` or `-j` flags to make.
- Make itself doesn't know any percentage of completed builds: it just starts building things and when it can't find anything else to build, it stops... so it has no idea how many more things are left to build.  CMake adds this percentage info to the makefiles it generates, and it's just a guesstimate.